# Keras cNN Transfer Model: Reduce Final Model Size?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working with multiple cNNs to be ran on mobile devices.  If I create these cNNs from scratch (black n white, 256x256), I'm able to produce a binary classification model of about 10mb, which is a size that would work great on a model device.

However, using transfer learning such as VG16 Imagenet gives my much better classification accuracy.  But, the model size is closer 100mb!  That is 10x as big as from scratch.  I have to take those grayscale images from scratch and convert them to 3 channel, which accounts for some of the size.  Also, freezing less layers, like 10 instead of 14 reduces the size, but very slightly.

Any suggestion on a way I can still leverage Keras Transfer learning and produce a much smaller model (like a way there a transfer learning model that is B&W)?

Here is my Transfer baseline model:

```
def baseline_model_func():
vgg_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(input_dim, input_dim, 3))

for layer in vgg_model.layers[:10]:
    layer.trainable = False

x = vgg_model.output
x = Flatten()(x) # use global pooling
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model_final = Model(inputs = vgg_model.input, outputs = predictions)
model_final.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), 
                    metrics=["accuracy"])
return model_final
```

`

Here is my cNN from scratch baseline model:

```
def baseline_model_func():
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', 
                        input_shape=(input_dim, input_dim, channel_numbers)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
return model
```

```